# Reference workbook where it contains specific text in filename?

Tags: excel, vba

I have had help from @user3598756 with this code.

I am trying to copy values from my slave workbook to my master workbook.

My slave workbook can change name from time to time, but will always include 'depot memo' or 'Depot Memo' in the title.

```
Food Depot Memo
DRINKS DEPOT MEMO
Bakery depot memo 123
```

So far I have the below code which works if the filename contains 'Depot Memo' with capital letters.

However, this code doesn't work if the 'depot memo' is in lower case.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oCell As Range, targetCell As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column I has changed
        If Not GetWb("Depot Memo", ws2) Then Exit Sub

        With ws2
            For Each targetCell In Target
                Set oCell = .Range("J1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not oCell Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -3)
                     targetCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 8)
                   
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function GetWb(wbNameLike As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*" & wbNameLike & "*" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "Depot Memo"
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetWb = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer, and its relatively simple.

All that needs to be added to the top of the module is:

```
 Option Compare Text
```

This essentially removes the case sensitivity

Full Code

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oCell As Range, targetCell As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column I has changed
        If Not GetWb("Depot Memo", ws2) Then Exit Sub

        With ws2
            For Each targetCell In Target
                Set oCell = .Range("J1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not oCell Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -3)
                     targetCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 8)

                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function GetWb(wbNameLike As String, ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*" & wbNameLike & "*" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "Depot Memo"
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetWb = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: @ManishChristian it says i cannot until 2 days from now

Answer (score 0):

Implement something like this into your code to uppercase your slave workbook name, and then checks to see if it contains "DEPOT MEMO".

```
    Sub Example()
        Dim IncomingWBName As String
        IncomingWBName = "Drinks DEPOT Memo" 'Set incoming name
        IncomingWBName = UCase(IncomingWBName) 'Set all to uppercase
        If InStr(IncomingWBName, "DEPOT MEMO") > 0 Then 'In String?
            MsgBox "Contains DEPOT MEMO"
            'Do something
        Else
            MsgBox "Doesn't contain DEPOT MEMO"
            'Do Something else
        End If
    End Sub
```

---Implemented into your code---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oCell As Range, targetCell As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column I has changed
        If Not GetWb(ws2) Then Exit Sub

        With ws2
            For Each targetCell In Target
                Set oCell = .Range("J1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=targetCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not oCell Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -3)
                     targetCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 8)

                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function GetWb(ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If InStr(UCase(wb.Name), "DEPOT MEMO") > 0 Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "DEPOT MEMO"
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetWb = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: thanks but how are you acquiring the workbook name in the first instance in order to capitalise it?

Comment: @user7415328 I have implemented my code into your code. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.